# The average number of solutions of syndrome decoding

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

It is well-known that the syndrome decoding problem of code is as followed: Let $C$ be an $[n,k,d]_q$
linear code, given party check matrix $H \in F_q^{(n-k)\times n}$, and syndrome $s$, find the error $e \in F_q^{n}$ with weight $w(e) \leq w$ such that $He=s$.

Let $R = \frac{k}{n}$ be the rate, and $W = \frac{w}{n}$ be the relative error.

The following paper (Refencence) stated that the average number of solutions depends on the relation $W$ and the relative distance $W_{GV}$ given by the Gilbert-Varshamov bound $W_{GV} = h_2(1-R)$.

[image]

I want to know why the average number of solutions depends on the relative error and the distance given by Gilbert-Varshamov bound. For example, why there is high probability a unique solution when W<<WGV. I know that when $w \leq \frac{d-1}{2}$, there is a unique solution, but I dont know why these three cases is true.

Reference: *Bricout, Rémi; Chailloux, André; Debris-Alazard, Thomas; Lequesne, Matthieu*, [**Ternary Syndrome Decoding with large weight**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-38471-5_18), Paterson, Kenneth G. (ed.) et al., Selected areas in cryptography – SAC 2019. 26th international conference, Waterloo, ON, Canada, August 12–16, 2019. Revised selected papers. Cham: Springer. Lect. Notes Comput. Sci. 11959, 437-466 (2020). [ZBL1453.94064](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1453.94064).

Comment: can you be more explicit about your question? state *exactly* what you want to know.

Comment: I want to know why the average number of solutions depends on the relative error and the distance given by  Gilbert-Varshamov bound, for example, why there is high probability a unique solution when  $W << W_{GV}$. I know that when $w \leq \frac{d-2}{2}$, there is a unique solution, but I dont know why these three cases is true. @kodlu

Comment: The syndrome decoding problem seems to be not stated correctly. For coding theorists, the problem is: given syndrome $s$,  to find the vector $e$ of _least_ weight such that $He =s$.  Note that $s$ is specified, and $e$ is unknown. There are (in the binary case) $2^k$ vectors $e$ such that $He$ equals the specified $s$; we want the vector of least weight among these $2^k$.  For some $s$, the $e$ of least weight is unique; for others, it is not.

Comment: Thanks. When we consider the worse-case complexity of the decoding algorithm,  we simply regard the weight of error as w, where $w = \frac{d-1}{2}$. Some code-based cryptosystem exactly depend on this hardness problem. But for general, I edited my question.